# XSL doesn't transform an array given as parameter

Tags: xslt

I have in my XSL file a template "printRestrictions" to transform an array given as parameter to my converter object:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="this xsl" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="destinationRestriction"/>
    <xsl:template name="printRestrictions">
        <xsl:param name="array"/>
        <xsl:if test="$array">
            <xsl:for-each select="$array/item">
                <restriction><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></restriction>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="af:ascframe">
        <ascstatistic>
            <destination>
                <restrictions>
                     <xsl:call-template name="printRestrictions">
                        <xsl:with-param name="array" select="$destinationRestriction"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </restrictions>
            </destination>
        </ascstatistic>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am giving to my converter a NodeList object (org.w3c.dom) containing two items.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    Element child = doc.createElement("item");
    child.setAttribute("value", "id1");
    rootElement.appendChild(child);

    Element child2 = doc.createElement("item2");
    child2.setAttribute("value", "id2");
    rootElement.appendChild(child2);

    NodeList childrenRestrictionsIds = rootElement.getChildNodes();
```

But after the transformation, only the first item is inserted in my output object. Not both.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us a full, working XSLT stylesheet where your problem is present, including an input XML if it matters. Especially the definition of `$destinatonRestriction` would be crucial.

Comment: Conventions for passing parameters to stylesheets depend on which XSLT processor you are using. You haven't told us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of

```
Element child2 = doc.createElement("item2");
```

you want

```
Element child2 = doc.createElement("item");
```

Or you need to change the XSLT to say `<xsl:for-each select="$array/*">`.